# My entire text in aspx page font be in arial. How to change it in css

Tags: css

My aspx page font is need to be changed .
I tried this :

```
 html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: arial;
}
```

its giving me the font in san sarif

Comment: do you have arial installed? also note, sans serif is not a font, it is type of font, arial is sans serif too

Comment: Have you tried changing the font in the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the CSS, so just change the `font-family` to that of what you are looking for.   You didn't mention what font you want...  but here are a few common settings...

**Sans-Serif**

- font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
- font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif
- font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif

**Serif**

- font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif
- font-family:Georgia, serif

And to add... you mentioned your code is giving you a sans-serif font.  Arial **IS** a sans-serif font, so this would be as expected.